# Generate a hash from a list of hashes

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm new to JS and I'm trying to figure out how I can take a list of hashes and convert them to  one hash. For example,

```
lst = [{"a": 10, "b": 2}, {"a": 10, "c": 5}, {"a": 10, "b": 2, "d": 20}]
```

to:

```
hash = {"a": 10, "b": 2, "c": 5, "d": 20}
```

What is the best way to do this? I was trying to use underscore's `map` in some way, but I'm not sure that is best approach.

Comment: Generally, `_.extend`, but what if the values disagree? For example: `[{a: 10}, {a: 20, b: 2}]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) :

```
var hash = lst.reduce(function(r,o){ for (var k in o) r[k]=o[k]; return r }, {});
```

Comment: +1 my gosh that was a very quick one.  is it possible for a working fiddle to see in action?

Comment: Note : As Google halted the support of IE9 in GMail, I can halt the support of IE8 in SO ;)

Comment: @dandavis There's NO reason to filter prototype properties here. Don't protect your code against the idiot who might change `Object.prototype`.

Comment: This works only for IE9+. If you want to make it run on IE8, you should look here: https://github.com/xhroot/jQuery-reduce-plugin/blob/master/jQuery.reduce.js

Comment: @HenriqueBarcelos There are also a number of polyfills available so you can still use the standardized method. MDN [offers a good one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce#Compatibility).

Comment: @HenriqueBarcelos: That patch doesn't follow the standard  implementation. Better to use a compliant one.

Comment: @dystroy: hmm, never heard anyone advocate unfiltered loops, all the best-practices i've seen say to use hasOwnProperty() to create more reliable and defensive routines. I also like how the extra typing required to do bullet-proof for loops makes Object.keys(o).map(...) all the more appealing...

Comment: Those "best practices" are mostly FUD, just like the one of not comparing to `undefined` in case it's shadowed or pretending that `eval` is always evil (it's just always slow and sometimes dangerous). There are times when you should filter and times when it's useless.